# What is the difference between built-in sum() and math.fsum() in Python 3.12?

Tags: python, sum, python-3.12

In the [What's New document](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#other-language-changes:%7E:text=sum()%20now%20uses%20Neumaier%20summation) for 3.12 there is a point:

> sum() now uses Neumaier summation to improve accuracy and commutativity when summing floats or mixed ints and floats. (Contributed by Raymond Hettinger in gh-100425.)

But also there is a [`math.fsum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum) function that is intended to be used for exact floating-point number summation. I guess it should be using some similar algorithm.

I tried different cases on 3.11 and 3.12. On 3.11 `sum()` gives less precise results as expected. But on 3.12 they always return the same good results and I wasn't able to find a case when it differs.

Which one should I use? Is there cases left when one should prefer [`math.fsum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum) over built-in [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the GitHub issue from your question: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100425

According to the detailed discussion there, `sum` has been about 10x faster that `fsum`. This new optimisation is supposed to run in parallel to the summation, making it essentially free.

`sum` is now more accurate than before. `fsum` should still be even more accurate in certain cases and slower. That seems to be its point.

If the accuracy of `sum` results is acceptable to you or you need its speed, then you can go with it.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It clarified many of my questions.